# parsing parentheses from a string

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, parsec

So I have a logical statement such as "((A o B) a B) o (B a C)" and I want to parse each set of statements within the parenthesis to each part in a list... here is what I have so far but since im new to haskell I have no idea if im on the right track
edit: I now have this again.
So the problem now is two things!!
(1) I have trouble returning a list of strings
(2) when I run it now I get unexpected '('

```
statement :: Parser String
statement =  many (letter <|> space ) >> parenStatement

parenStatement :: Parser [String]
parenStatement = do
    char '('
    answer <- statement
    char ')'
    return answer
```

Comment: it looks like you're making progress; keep plugging away! But I don't think this is a good fit for SO, because you don't understand your problem enough yet to have presented a real question.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you have some data type that represents a logical statement.

```
data Statement = Conjunction Statement Statement
               | Disjunction Statement Statement
               -- etc
```

Presumably you ultimately want to be able to parse logical statements.

```
statement :: Parser Statement
statement = conjunction <|> disjunction <|> parenthesisisedStatement -- etc
```

Parsing a statement surrounded by parentheses is then just

```
parenthesisisedStatement :: Parser Statement
parenthesisisedStatement = do
    char '('
    answer <- statement
    char ')'
    return parenthesisisedStatement
```

---

**Edit:** (because this won't fit into a comment)

You appear to be trying to **tokenise** your input string into a list of strings (that you might later feed into a parser). You do not seem to be trying to **parse** your input string into a data structure that properly constrains what it may contain.

If you really want to **tokenise** your input, I advise asking again in a new top level question.

But you are probably better off **parsing** your input into a proper data structure, so **think about how best to represent statements** and **[don't just use](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) [strings everywhere](http://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=14876)**.

Comment: The data type is a string. and Thanks for the insight

Comment: although this does not use seperators and will not give me all the seperated () right?